# RavenDb use proxy server from IE

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, proxy, ravendb

I have a desktop application that uses RavenDb to retrieve and write data. Some of my clients have a proxy server specified in IE (which is some kind of central proxy server for Windows; Chrome uses the same proxy server) and RavenDb client can not get access to the database server as it does not take proxy server into account. Is there a way to specify a proxy server for RavenDb connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure proxy settings in the `<defaultProxy>` elements in your app.config file.

Comment: I think you can do that using `WebProxy` class